# Graficar Funcion en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola que tal como estas?

Como haría para graficar las siguientes lineas de código?

```
pSup = float(amplitud.get()) * (float(tiempo.get())**3)
obj = pSup / 1.62
funcion=log10(obj)
```

ya que lo he intentado de diferentes formas y no me grafica ya que muestra un error en consola sobre el log10()

Agradecería de antemano sus ayudas.

Comment: Tú dices: *ya que lo he intentado de diferentes formas ....*, podrias mostrar lo que has intentado aunque no funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que quiera graficar funcion. Una recomendación  es usar la librería `numpy` para las funciones logaritmo. Por ejemplo

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    F = np.log10(obj)
    plt.plot(F), plt.show()
```

Nota: para mejorar la calidad de la respuesta se necesita más información sobre las variables amplitud y tiempo.